# Laravel 5.6: Obtener suma de un campo de una tabla usando sum y where

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$tiendas=Tienda::with('factura.cuenta.cuentapago.pago')
                    ->where('cuenta.id_tcuenta','=','1')
                    ->join('ventas.factura', 'tienda.id', '=', 'factura.id_tienda')
                    ->join('cuentas.cuenta', 'factura.id', '=', 'cuenta.id_factura')
                    ->leftJoin('cuentas.cuenta_pago', 'cuenta.id', '=', 'cuenta_pago.id_cuenta')
                    ->leftJoin('cuentas.pago', 'cuenta_pago.id_pago', '=', 'pago.id')
                    ->where('cuenta.pagada', '=', false)
                    ->where('factura.casa_m', '=', false)
                    ->where('cuenta.estatus', '=', true) // Solo tiendas con cuenta con status true
                    //->where('pago.estatus', '=', true)
                    ->select('tienda.*', 
                                DB::raw('COUNT(distinct cuenta.id) as n_facturas'), 
                                DB::raw('SUM(cuenta.m_total) as m_total'),
                                DB::raw('SUM(cuenta.m_iva) as miva_total'),
                                DB::raw('SUM(pago.m_total) as m_total2'))
                    ->groupBy('tienda.id','tienda.nombre')
                    ->get();
```

En m_total2 sumo los campos montos totales de la tabla pago. Sin embargo la tabla pago tiene otro campo llamado estatus que es de tipo booleano. Quiero usar el sum con un where pago.estatus = true.

Lo intente de esta forma pero me da error:

```
  DB::raw('SUM(pago.m_total) as m_total2')->where('pago.estatus', '=', true))
```

Comment: con la última consulta que error obtienes?

Comment: "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::where()"

Answer (score 1):

Prueba la siguiente query:

```
$tiendas=Tienda::where('cuenta.id_tcuenta','=','1')
                    ->join('factura', 'tienda.id', '=', 'factura.id_tienda')
                    ->join('cuenta', 'factura.id', '=', 'cuenta.id_factura')
                    ->leftJoin('cuenta_pago', 'cuenta.id', '=', 'cuenta_pago.id_cuenta')
                    ->leftJoin('pago', 'cuenta_pago.id_pago', '=', 'pago.id')
                    ->where('cuenta.pagada', '=', false)
                    ->where('factura.casa_m', '=', false)
                    ->where('cuenta.estatus', '=', true) 
                    ->where('pago.estatus', '=', true)
                    ->select('tienda.*', 
                                DB::raw('COUNT(distinct cuenta.id) as n_facturas'), 
                                DB::raw('SUM(cuenta.m_total) as m_total'),
                                DB::raw('SUM(cuenta.m_iva) as miva_total'),
                                DB::raw('SUM(pago.m_total) as m_total2'))
                    ->groupBy('tienda.id','tienda.nombre')
                    ->get();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Bienvenido!!! podrias mirar el [tour] y tambien [answer]?. Siempre se pide que expliques que soluciona este codigo y que cosas cambiaste con respecto al original, para que quede claro cual es el problema y la solución.